# How can i return the value of my userID with firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(), it currently returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to retrieve the userID of the current user but it returns undefined.
How can i fix this?

```
getUser = async () => {
    let userID
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            userID = user.uid.toString()
            console.log(userID) // return the userID
        }
    })
    return userID
}
```

```
export const writeUserData = async (weight, reps, date, pathExercice) => {
    let pathID = await getUser()
    console.log(pathID) // returns undefined
    firebase.database().ref('users/9DLCsvffRRccr5e7YxPulzzjh2n1/' + pathExercice).push({
        weight,
        reps,
        date
    }).then((data) => {
        // console.log('data ', data)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('error ', error)
    })
}
```

Comment: found an easier solution : let pathID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getUser()` function uses a callback, which has nothing to do with the `async/await` feature of JS: the user id is returned before the callback is triggered.

Using the `firebase.auth().currentUser` is the way to go. Check the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: Thank you for you reply, found the same solution a bit earlier, but still, thank you :)